# Getting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' accessing a web api

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7, jsonp

I am trying to consume a simple web api that returns the data below in Objective C using `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

```
Results; (
    {
    Category = Groceries;
    Id = 1;
    Name = "Tomato Soup";
    Price = 1;
},
    {
    Category = Toys;
    Id = 2;
    Name = "Yo-yo";
    Price = "3.75";
},
    {
    Category = Hardware;
    Id = 3;
    Name = Hammer;
    Price = "16.99";
}
)
```

My Objective-C call looks like this:

```
//not the real URL, just put in to show the variable being set
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someapi"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;    
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request

                                                            success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                NSLog(@"Results; %@", JSON);
                self.resultsArray= [JSON objectForKey:@"Results"];
             }

                                                            failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error ,id JSON) {
                 //http status code
                 NSLog(@"Received Error: %d", response.statusCode);
                 NSLog(@"Error is: %@", error);
             }
             ];

//run service
[operation start];
```

When I run my code, I can see the data returned in the NSLog statement. However I get the following error when I try to set the results to my array using the JSON objectForKey statement.

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe466510
2013-09-30 20:49:03.893 ITPMessageViewer[97459:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe466510'
```

I'm fairly new to Objective-C, and can't figure out why this isn't working. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: That web API doesn't look right. It could be copy paste errors, but it's better to check. If results is an array it should be surrounded by '[]'. In addition, what's with "Results;", and then an open parenthesis? Should that be a brace ('{')?

Answer (score 4):

The result you are getting is an Array

`objectForKey:` is a NSDictionary method

So use `valueForKey:` which is a NSArray method.

```
self.resultsArray= [JSON valueForKey:@"Results"];
```

Comment: @user2167593 If you find any of the answers useful please **upvote it** and if answer is correct then please **accept it** this will help to remove the question from the list of **unanswered list of question**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That eliminated the error, but I am not getting any data passed into the array.  When I inspect the Json object in debug mode, I see 3 empty array fields [0], [1], [2].  The NSLog still outputs the data fine, but its not getting loaded into the array at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the JSON ( result ) need to follow this method to use :

```
    self.resultsArray = (NSArray *)JSON;
```

It'll force the " id " type to NSArray for your self.resultsArray type ( It is an NSArray, right ? ), then you can use this method to enumerate it.

```
    [self.resultsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        NSDictionary *_eachResult = (NSDictionary *)obj;
        [_eachResult objectForKey:@"Category"];
        //... 
    }];
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.  I didn't see the data being passed in your suggestion, so I substituted obj for JSON.  Code runs but data is not loaded into resultsArray (yes this is an NSArray).  I think the data is in a format that can't be parsed easily.  Looking at that now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to update my web service to return data in a format that the AFJSONRequestOperation was happy with.  This allowed me to get the JSON to parse properly.  Still not sure why it needed this dictionary combo, but glad it worked.

In case anyone is writing a web api in C# to talk to objective C, this is what I did:

The update was to return the following object as JSON (code is in C#).

Dictionary > with string = "results" and the IEnumerable is my strongly typed array of objects.

```
public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllProducts()
        {
            var sortedProuct = results.OrderBy(a => a.Category);

            var proddict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Product>>()
            {
                { "results", results}, 
            };

            return proddict;
        }
```

this translates to:

```
Results; {
results = ({
Category = Groceries;
Id = 1;
Name = "Tomato Soup";
Price = 1;},
```

....